# Textview.Text to spinner

Tags: android, xamarin

i'm trying send a value from a textview to a spinner.Here is my code:

```
TextView textview1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.descriptiontext);
Spinner ts = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.categorytext);

        String textview5;
        textview5 = ts.ToString();

         textview5=textview1.Text;
```

But unfortunately nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how different Xamarin is to Java Android SDK, but I had a look at the documentation and it seemed pretty similar.

To set text to a Spinner you have to use an adapter. In this case an `ArrayAdapter`. You have to create a `List` of strings and create an `ArrayAdapter` for it, which you can then assign to the Spinner.

You can use this code for reference: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/spinner/

Here, the ArrayAdapter is created from a resource. You want to create it from a list. You can use the ArrayAdapter reference to find a constructor that best suits your needs. https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.ArrayAdapter/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try casting TextView and Spinner this way

```
TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(Resource.Id.descriptiontext);
Spinner ts = (Spinner) findViewById(Resource.Id.categorytext);
```